# Create alphanumeric sequence depending on field on Postgresql table

Tags: postgresql

I want to create an alphanumeric sequence in postgresql. Table name is commerces it consists of five columns.

id,
type,
name,
logo,
parent (this is a reference to itself)

In id I want to generate ID like 'G1000000', 'C1000000' or 'S1000000' based on type field. Type is an ENUM with three possible values: 'chain', 'group' or 'store' so when I insert a new group I expect an id: 'G1000001' and when I insert a new store I expect an id: 'S1000001' and so on.

How to create this type sequence.

Comment: You don't expect these sequences to be gap-less, right? Best use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As @LaurenzAlbe stated, you should think about a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dd03c7e55123f957b315a4d217d71b89)

Trigger Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_id() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
    type_part text;
    value_part int;
BEGIN
  SELECT                                                          -- 1
      CASE
          WHEN NEW.type = 'chain' THEN 'C'
          WHEN NEW.type = 'group' THEN 'G'
          WHEN NEW.type = 'store' THEN 'S'
      END
  INTO type_part;
  
  SELECT                                                          -- 2
      COALESCE(MAX(substring(id FROM 2)::int), 999999) + 1
  INTO value_part
  FROM
      t
  WHERE t.type = NEW.type;
  
  
  NEW.id = type_part || value_part;                               -- 3
  
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

1. Calculate the `id` prefix
2. Fetch the current max value for the appropriate type and adds `1` for the new `id`. `COALESCE()` is for the case, you don't have any values, so it sets the initial values. Can be left out if you you already have some values
3. Concatenate both parts

Naturally, it is possible to combine both statements, I split them up for increased readability:

```
  SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN NEW.type = 'chain' THEN 'C'
          WHEN NEW.type = 'group' THEN 'G'
          WHEN NEW.type = 'store' THEN 'S'
      END || COALESCE(MAX(substring(id FROM 2)::int), 999999) + 1
  INTO new_id
  FROM
      t
  WHERE t.type = NEW.type;
```

Afterwards, create the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_generate_id
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON t
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE generate_id();
```

Comment: afact the above still can lead to duplicates when  run concurrently from different transactions, at least when using the default transaction isolation that Postgresql has.
I haven't yet found any different way other than sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept gaps in the sequences you can get close to what you are looking for by creating 3 sequences, and selecting the appropriate one based on the "type" column.
See [full example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=74c0affd48f51cacb9df889723ac212a) here.

```
create sequence chain_seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999;
create sequence group_seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999;
create sequence store_seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999;

create or replace function some_table_gin_id()
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql 
as $$
begin 
    new.id = 
        case when new.type_cd = 'chain' 
             then 'C' || to_char(nextval('chain_seq'),'FM0000009')  
             
             when new.type_cd = 'group'  
             then 'G' || to_char(nextval('group_seq'),'FM0000009')
             
             when new.type_cd = 'store'  
             then 'S' || to_char(nextval('store_seq'),'FM0000009')
        end ; 
    return new;
end ;
$$;
```

Keep in mind that at some point you **will have gaps**. If you require gap-less generated ids then the suggestion by @S-Man is as good as any. But you must handle duplicates. This is still a MAX+1 solution. All such solutions, in a multi-user environment, are virtually ***guaranteed*** to generate duplicates at some point.